# Why my bluetooth headset device is visible on my phone but not on my computer?

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I can connect to my bluetooth "headset" (Belkin HD BT S57) using my phone, but it is not visible to my computer (Ubuntu 14.10).

[I tried](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96693/connect-to-a-bluetooth-device-via-terminal) `bluetooth-wizard`, `hcitool scan`, `hidd --search` and `bt-device -l`, but none of them listed the device (I have another headset, Rocket Fish MAB2, that *is* visible to my computer).

How do I make this work?

Comment: Have you turned your phone bluetooth off? (Disconnected the device.)

Comment: @user367890, yeah, the phone's bluetooth was off.

Comment: OK. Only checking (As, if connected to any other device it is perhaps not broadcasting.)

Comment: Is it this one? http://www.belkin.com/us/support-article?articleNum=7974

Comment: @user367890, yes.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the particular device, but I know that Bluetooth earpieces (used not as headphones, but for answering calls etc.) often can be paired to a single device. If I wanted to use my Jabra EasyGo, for example, on 2 different phones, I'd have to unpair it from one to pair it with the second.

Comment: @JoeSewell, as I mentioned, the device was unpaired.

Comment: `bluetoothctl` is part of Bluez 5. Looks like Ubuntu 14.10 comes with Bluez 4.

Comment: I didn't see you say it was **unpaired**, only that "the phone's bluetooth was off," which is not the same thing. Turning off BT on the phone **disconnects** the two devices, but both devices remember that they are paired. I've since looked at @user367890's link, and discovered the answer, which I'll put below.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.belkin.com/us/support-article?articleNum=7974

> QUICK TIP:  The HD Bluetooth Music Receiver will allow one (1) device to connect to it at a time.

The problem is the definition of "connect." It could mean that the device can only have a live Bluetooth connection with one other device at a time, **or** it could mean that the device can only know about one other device at a time.

As I mentioned in a comment above, Bluetooth earpieces used for phone conversations may only be able to know about one device at a time. This is often referred to as "pairing." Two devices can be paired but not connected. In fact, two powered-off devices can still be paired. When a device is paired to another one, it won't try to connect to any other device. Often it won't even be discoverable, meaning it won't show up in anyone else's device list.

From the support article cited above, after clicking on the link asking about using it with another device, it sounds like you have to unpair it from one device in order to pair it with another.

Comment: according to the user manual, it's enough to turn off the bluetooth on the paired device, so i think it's not an issue with the headset but rather with the computer. As evidance, I've unpaired the device *and* turned it off, but still the computer won't recongize it. Moreover, I renamed my phone in between, and it is still able to connect.

Comment: Bluetooth doesn't key off the name of the phone, but a unique ID shared during pairing.

Comment: I also tried with two different phones and it works fine.

Comment: OK, then that means this device can be paired with multiple other devices. Belkin used the correct terminology.